# Website keeps flickering in smaller screen sizes in safari

Tags: jquery, html, css, macos, safari

I have this site https://www.scit.com.br/

**This is working fine in all browsers except safari** in medium and smaller screens. The issue is that the page starts to flicker like zoom in and out. Inspect shows repeated :before and :after added in a tags. This is caused by style.css file.
I tried removing all js files so JS is not the culprit.

Later removing code by trail and error. I found that below css were causing the issue

style.css line: 2080, 2118, 2156, 2203

```
@media (min-width: 36rem) and (max-width: 47.9375rem) {
    html {
        font-size: 85%;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 48rem) and (max-width: 61.9375rem) {
    html {
        font-size: 90%;
    }

}

@media (min-width: 62rem) and (max-width: 74.9375rem) {
    html {
        font-size: 95%;
    }

}


@media (min-width: 75rem) {
    html {
        font-size: 100%;
    }
}
```

If I remove these styles it works.

My question is

- why is this happening ?
- what could be the root cause of this issue and how to fix it ?

Comment: Are you using media queries?  If it's flickering, my first guess would be that the change of the font-size is pushing something past the boundary of a media query, which is adjusting the font-size back past another media query boundary, so it's bouncing the style changes.

Comment: @Taplar Your opinion could be right in one way. Note that this happening only at transitions of different media queries. only possibility is may be safari is trying to make the media query below work in some odd way. like approximation or missing out some intermediate values or something. which I cant make out exactly
(max-width: 74.9375rem)  
(min-width: 75rem)

Answer (score 0):

Your media query rem units are based on your `html` font-size. So when one changes the other is changing too causing a loop or the bounce effect.

To fix this you could change your font-size to target something other than the `html` element, like `body`.

Comment: If that's the case then it must not work at all in entire Safari and all other browser. The issue occurs for me only in Safari and also only at the point where media queries change over to next smaller screen. Say like 74.9375rem to 75rem

Answer (score 0):

I have just come across this page having experienced the same issue myself. I was having flickers only on safari, all other browsers are ok.

**In short** - use ems

Within media queries em's and rem's should not be affected by changes in font-size in the HTML as they’re based on the browser’s internal font-size property - however it appears safari does't follow this rule for rems.

For example, by default a 25em min-width breakpoint kicks in at 400px and if you change the html font-size to 2rem it still comes in at 400px.
A 25rem min-width breakpoint with the html font size changed to 2rem will kick in at 800px in safari (example/artcile below from Zell Liew), which is different to the others.

I checked your code and noticed you applied a similar solution, switching rems for pxs, this will work but your pxs aren't very flexible and if the user increases their browser font sizes your breakpoints will stay the same

```
/*@media (min-width: 36rem) and (max-width: 47.9375rem) {*/
@media (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 767px) {
```

I came across this excellent article that explained things further
https://zellwk.com/blog/media-query-units/

And mocked this up from his examples to demonstrate visually
https://codepen.io/webknit/pen/KYLNVW